# GetEnvironmentVariable("CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA") returns null

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, windows-7

I'm trying to get the EnvironmentVariable "CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA" using the below statement

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA");
```

I expected to get "C:\ProgramData\" back. But I get null
I'm running my C# program on a Windows 7 32 bit machine. Please help.

Comment: Did you check if this variable exists in the environment? Open a cmd prompt and try it or list all available env vars from your code first

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA is not an environment variable, it is a constant that you pass to the SHGetFolderPath() winapi function. In C#, you can do that using Environment.GetFolderPath():

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
Console.WriteLine(path);
```

Output on a normal PC:

```
C:\ProgramData
```